# Double operations with FR or UK typed double

Tags: neo4j, cypher

### Description

If you want to store FR typed double in a node, you can only do it using `String` value, because double values are displayed like this: 12,58 (instead of 12.58 for US type).

So, if you want to do some computing in a cypher query, it's hard to use FR types doubles since they are `String`, and `String` + `String` results in a concatenation, not a real addition.

### Example

To check this problem, you can simply create two nodes:

```
CREATE (a:TestNode{value : "12,45"}), (b:TestNode{value : "15"})
RETURN (a.value + b.value) AS result
```

### Solutions ?

The obvious solution would be to store everything as double in the base, and do the computing on Java side, but it requires too much refactoring, and the problem is that some values are stored as FR double (like 1254,7898), some are stored as UK double (like 12,789.45) and some as US double (those ones are stored using the primitive type double).

I'm looking for a pure Cypher solution, to avoid massive data and code refactoring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question. You can handle the differently formatted doubles in a `CASE` expression. First, you convert it to a string. If it contains both `.` and `,` it's UK. Else if it contains `,` but not `.` it's FR. Else it should be a native double. You can then replace the `,` and convert to float.

```
MATCH (a:TestNode)
RETURN
CASE 
    // UK formatted, 12,3456.45
    WHEN toString(a.value) =~ ".*\\..*" AND toString(a.value) =~ ".*\\,.*"
    // remove , and convert to float
    THEN toFloat(replace(toString(a.value), ',', ''))
    // FR formatted 1234,23
    WHEN toString(a.value) =~ ".*\\,.*" AND NOT toString(a.value) =~ ".*\\..*"
    // replace, with . and convert to float
    THEN toFloat(replace(toString(a.value), ',', '.'))
    // else it should be a double
    ELSE toFloat(a.value)
END
```

**But** this query can only `RETURN` the `value` as a float/double. I don't know how you can include the `CASE` thing in a more complex query.

Comment: including this in a more complex query can be achieved using WITH I think, since a CASE clause should always be aliased, you can use it in a WITH clause